# Change already attached event handler runtime

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have created a `TextBox` dynamically and attached a Tap event handler to it using:

```
control.Tap += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs>(OnClick1);
```

It works fine. But, now I want to change the event handler to point to some different method. I tried:

```
control.Tap += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs>(OnClick2);
```

But, it still points to first event handler. i.e. `OnClick1`. What can I do to make it point `OnClick2`? Also is there a way to remove this event handler completely?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to remove the first handler first:

```
control.Tap -= OnClick1;
control.Tap += OnClick2;
```

(Note the rather simpler use of method group conversions, instead of explicitly creating the event handler. It does the same thing, but is much more readable.)